# Electrostatic potential energy of a conducting polo

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential-energy, conductors, self-energy

Consider a thick metallic sphere with inner radius R1 and outer radius R2 . Now charge q2 is given to the conductor and another charge q1 is held fixed at the centre. How do we calculate  the electrostatic  potential  energy  of  this system?

Do we add self energy of the charge on both inner and outer surface + individual energies or something  else.
Please  justify  the reason  also.
Thanks

Comment: What is a "polo"?

Comment: Thick hollow  metallic sphere ( with inner and outer radius)

Comment: Interesting. I've never encountered that word before outside of the context of shirts, water polo, and horseback polo. In my experience, a more standard term would be "thick spherical shell". There's potentially some redundancy in that name, but it's intentional as "sphere" and "ball" are often confused.

Answer (score -1):

suggest you start with [Feynman](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_08.html#:%7E:text=(8.9)%20the%20energy%20of%20a,the%20idea%20of%20electrostatic%20energy)

simplifying assumption is that the effect of the point charge at the center is the same as though there is a sphere of the empty radius with the same charge uniformly distributed

then there's two parts to consider - (i) solve the U1 for q1, r1; (ii) adapt the equation for the shell to get U2 from r1-r2 - just add them

Comment: Answers on this site should use proper grammar, capitalization, and punctuation. They should also use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for all mathematical symbols, expressions, equations, etc.

Comment: Could you please  elaborate.  What I am able to understand  is that we are counting  interaction energy of inner surface and q1 and self energy of outer surface. Am I correct? Could you please tell the reason as well